# How to fix NameError in input() function in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nameerror

I am currently running Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10. I am trying to use this code `print('Hello'+input())` but it's not working. When I input a name, say, John, after Python has printed 'Hello', it gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    John
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

I tried looking for solutions on the internet but most of them are talking about how `input()` should be `raw_input()` on Python 2.x but I couldn't find any solution for Python 3.x. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** (add screenshot from comment):
[image]

Comment: Is that all the code that get executed ? Otherwise, please provide the whole code snippet you are executing.

Comment: That's the whole code I'm trying to execute. Here's a screenshot of the whole thing for clarity: https://imgur.com/a/lX7K2wA

Comment: I would definitely check your python version. At the top of the script, do `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey Python version 3.7.2 because I got this  `3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx1DO.png), I think you're simply testing it incorrectly.

[image: wrong]

After typing `print('Hello'+input())` and pressing the Enter key, the console is already at the `input()` prompt (at the blank line), and is waiting for *your* input. **But instead, you pressed the Enter key again**, so `input()` receives an empty string and prints `"Hello"+""` which just prints `"Hello"`.

**When you type "John", it's already treated as the next line of code** (indicated by the `>>>`), which Python treats as a variable and it tries to print the value of `John` but that is clearly undefined, resulting in the error you see.

The correct way is, after entering `print('Hello'+input())`, just type `John` at the blank line, to pass it to `input()`:

[image: right]